# putting different posters at the beginning and ending of html5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can implement a poster at the beginning of a video using `poster="beginning.jpg"`, but how to put a different image at the end of video? example image is like `ending.jpg`

```
<video controls width="100%" poster="beginning.jpg" >
  <source src="video.mp4" />
</video>
```

here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ey4tfp30/1/)

Comment: did you read the question @guest271314? it is totally different

Comment: I want to display different image at the end

Comment: Yes. You can use same approaches at Answers at linked Question. Have you tried using `ended` event? What is different about current Question?

Comment: the question you marked is about displaying the same image (used in the beginning) at the end as well. however, I want to display different image not the image I used in the `poster="image"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ended`, `play` events, `.load()`

```
<video width="100%" controls poster="/image/src/">
  <source src="/video/src/" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<script>
  var video = document.querySelector("video");
  video.onplay = function() {
    this.setAttribute("poster", "") // remove `poster` image
  video.onended = function(e) { 
     this.setAttribute("poster", "/new/image/src") // set new `poster` image
     // call `.load()`
     this.load();
  }
</script>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ey4tfp30/4/

Answer (score 0):

First add an Id to the video.

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var posterURL = 'end.jpg';

// Preload the end poster when the video starts to play
video.addEventListener('play', function() {
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = posterURL;
});

// Set and display the end poster
video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
  video.poster = posterURL;
  video.load();
});
```

Comment: The new image still needs to load, old image could still be viewed before new images loads, as noted at  comments at the linked Question which you shared.